# Intersecting several layers in FME

Tags: layers, intersection, fme-form, fme-transformer

I am trying to intersect multiple line layers (in FME: feature types) against 1 layer. Therefore I am using LineOnLine Overlayer in FME 2021 but without any success so far. Transformer is going all the incoming layers through but I want lets say layers 'a', 'b' and 'c' only against layer 'd' to be checked and not with each other. Any hint?

Comment: Perhaps the LineOnLineOverlayer is not the correct tool for your purposes. It splits lines at intersections. Is that what you want?  Do you just want to know which features from layers A, B, C which intersect with layer D? Have you looked at the SpatialFilter or SpatialRelator? Alternatively, the LineOnLineOverlayer can also store the attributes of incoming features. You could then filter out features which intersect with layer D.

Comment: actually I want my lines to be splitted but only if there is intersection with layer D..... I have in layer A many line features which intersect one another but thats OK it should be like that. What I want is: every single feature of layer A to be checked for intersection against layer D. Currently I get all lines splitted even for the overlaying features in the layer A and that is not what I want. I also tried SpatialFilter and SpatialRelator, they are able to find all the overlaying features but they dont splitt them.

Comment: Please expand your question with such vital info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution I found: apply SpatialFilter (layer a with layer d) before LineOnLine Overlayer. In this way we avoid intersection of features inside layer d with each other, and we get only features that intersect layer d and connect to LineOnLine Overlayer. it produces results I needed.

[image]